# Export sql server registration info from VIsual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

how can i export all my sql server registered in SQL Server Object Explorer?

I try `Import and export settings` but it dont save them

Comment: i lost 2 time all registered info, so a way to make a backup will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's not a built-in mechanism that will save and restore these settings.  The connection string data is saved in the registry under

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStrings
```

so you could perhaps export the settings from there.

> The standard disclaimers about editing the registry being dangerous apply, as always.