# Visual Studio 2013 Database Designer - how to visually edit view

Tags: visual-studio, view, sql-server-data-tools

in visual studio 2013 i find way to use designer when i add a new view (i have SQL Server Data Tools and use data connection in server explorer with oledb type) but the problem is that, once created, i see no way to use editor to alter it.

i have many and many query create with sintax used by editor and try to edit them manually is a drama.

since db object can be managed with visual studio, our company remove sql server management studio from our pc to save licences.

i find many discussion here on how to use editor to create view but noone about how to edit existing one

Comment: Did I miss something in SSMS requiring licenses to use? If you're using SQL Server it should be included in that. Worst case scenario, buy the Developer edition so you can get SSMS through that at $50/seat. But maybe Jamie Thomson's article can help - http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2014/09/26/connected-development-10-days-of-ssdt-day-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To edit views after creation, the recommended way is to connect in SQL Server Object Explorer rather than Server Explorer. Then double-click on the View to open an editor, make changes, and click the "Update" button to publish those changes.

You can also use Server Explorer for this but you need to connect using the ".Net Framework Data Provider for SQL Server", **not** the OLE DB connection.

Finally, SSMS is 100% free to download and use. The latest preview is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt238290.aspx), with 2014 release installable from the [SQL Server 2014 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) page - choose one of the SQLManagementStudio links. You do not need a paid SQL Server license to install the tools.

**Disclosure**: I work on the SQL Server Data Tools team.

Comment: after you answer i deep the things, SSMS was removed since now it's installed only on sysadmin machine. for (poor) developer only visual studio is left. and honestly is much better doing all from visual studio than switching from VS to SSMS (our machine barely support VS and a browser running). i try to use ".Net Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" but it open sql code, not graphical editor. my question is why i can create it in graphycal way with oledb, and then i have no more way to edit it at same way

Comment: p.s. @kevin,  can yot take a look to this question about ssdt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114646/export-sql-server-registration-info-from-visual-studio

Comment: In short: SSDT does not provide a View Designer. I was not aware the OLEDB connection type supports this and don't know why it would allow creation but not editing.

Comment: for the other question, Steven Green from my team has given an answer, hope that it helps resolve your issue

Comment: for info: read dvc answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ed4675d3-aa84-47db-bdf5-f852355409e6/query-designer-not-displaying-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=ssdt. thanks for other reply